# Forming a sequence of address lists with input from multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm constructing a sequence of structured address for searching in Google maps.
I have added `ng-change` in all the text box to collect data.
The adddress follows as ..

1. Address line1
2. Address line2
3. Area
4. City
5. State
6. Country

So when the user starts entering in any of the field the address should construct itself as ..

Eg: "Address line1,Address line2,Area,City,Country"

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
      <label class="label"> Address Line1</label>
    <input type="text" name="addressline1" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.line1"/>

     <label class="label"> Address Line1</label>
    <input type="text" name="addressline2" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.line2"/>

     <label class="label"> Area</label>
    <input type="text" name="area" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.area"/>

     <label class="label"> City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.city"/>

     <label class="label">   State</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.state"/>

     <label class="label">Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.country"/>
    </div>
   <div class="row">{{enteredAddress}}<?div>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.getAddresss=function (address) {
         if (address.addressLine1) {
                address = address.concat(',' + address.addressLine1);
            } else {
                address = address.addressLine1;
            }
            if (address.addressLine2) {
                address = address.concat(',' + address.addressLine2);
            } else {
                address = address.addressLine2;
            }
            if (address.area) {
                address = address.concat(',' + address.area);
            } else {
                address = address.area;
            }
            if (address.city) {
                address = address.concat(',' + address.city);
            } else {
                address = address.city;
            }
            if (address.state) {
                address = address.concat(',' + address.state);
            } else {
                address = address.state;
            }
            $scope.enteredAddress=address;
        }
```

But this logic fails in multiple conditions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `Array#map` over `Object.keys` and then `Array#join`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.address = {
    line1: '',
    line2: '',
    area: '',
    city: '',
    state: '',
    country: ''
  };
  $scope.enteredAddress = '';
  $scope.getAddress = function(address) {
    var address = Object.keys(address).map(function(item) {
      return address[item];
    }).filter(Boolean);
    $scope.enteredAddress = address.join(', ');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  <div class="row">
    <label class="label">Address Line1</label>
    <input type="text" name="addressline1" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.line1" />{{address.line1}}
    <label class="label">Address Line1</label>
    <input type="text" name="addressline2" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.line2" />
    <label class="label">Area</label>
    <input type="text" name="area" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.area" />
    <label class="label">City</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.city" />

    <label class="label">State</label>
    <input type="text" name="state" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.state" />
    <label class="label">Country</label>
    <input type="text" name="country" ng-change="getAddress(address)" ng-model="address.country" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">{{enteredAddress}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Object.keys` gives keys in arbitrary order.

Comment: And this wont filter empty values.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, `filter` is fine but first reason was quiet _deep_..Thanks for that ;) Dealing with hard coded keys is the only option ?

Comment: You can't predict the order of iteration with `Object.keys` since it is the same as `for... in` but w/o inherited properties. So I think yes, the only way is to set properties list first.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, Check the update! In this way, if the keys are there in `object`, provided order will be followed.. Correct me I am am assuming wrong things ;)

Comment: Still there is no guarantee. Though modern engines will return properties in order they were declared in literal. And still it's kinda the same as properties list but in some indirect manner. :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I doubt that as _MDN_ says, _`Object.keys()` returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object_

Comment: *in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop* which is *The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.*

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.getAddresss = function(address) {

var add1, add2, area, city, state, country;

if (address.addressLine1) {
add1 = address.addressLine1 + ', ';
}
if (address.addressLine2) {
add2 = address.addressLine2 + ', ';
}
if (address.area) {
area = address.area + ', ';
}
if (address.city) {
city = address.city + ', ';
}
if (address.state) {
state = address.state + ', ';
}

$scope.enteredAddress = add1 + add2 + area + city + state + country;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make it work by using

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("addressController", function($scope) {
    $scope.getAddress = function(address) {
        var line1 = $scope.address.line1 || '';
        var line2 = $scope.address.line2 || '';
        var area = $scope.address.area || '';
        var city = $scope.address.city || '';
        var state = $scope.address.state || '';
        var country = $scope.address.country || '';
        $scope.enteredAddress = line1 + ',' + line2 + ',' + area + ',' + city + ',' + state + ',' + country;
    };
});
```

Here is the [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LkURwXvFfFOP7il8oXYZ?p=preview)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the solution.But how can I avoid the multiple commas(,) that comes in between if I don't enter any text?

Comment: @forgottofly code is updated in the link, but you can use Rayon answer. Its very effective and optimized :)

Answer (score 1):

Be more declarative

```
$scope.getAddress = function(address) {
    $scope.enteredAddress = 'line1|line2|area|city|state'
           .split('|') //create properties ordered list (array)
           .map(function(name) { return address[name]}) //get values
           .filter(Boolean) //remove empty
           .join(', '); //join with comma
}
```